# Reading and writing to a CSV file in pseudocode

Tags: csv, pseudocode

I am just starting on my NEA and I need to write a simple account maker for my game, so like login register play as guest etc. But I don't know how to check details of a CSV file and compare it to the values entered by the user. My code so far is printed down below help would be much appreciated:

```
account()
{
    choice = print("
    
    [1] Register 
    [2] Login 
    [3] Play as guest 
    [4] Quit")
    
    if choice == 1
        user_register()
    else if choice == 2
        user_login()
    else if choice == 3
        user_guest()
    else
        closeProgram
    

    user_login()
    {
        nickname = print("Enter nickname")
       password = print("Enter password")
       check_details() 
    }
    
    user_register()
    {
        nickname = print("Enter nickname")
        password = print("Enter password")
        write_details()
    }
    
    user_guest()
    {
        nickname = print("Enter nickname")
    }
    check_details()
    {
        myFile = openRead("accountDetails.csv")
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "NEA" ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.